# URL Hacking - Trying to incorporate a unique count at the end of a pre-populated field

Tags: opportunity, master-detail, button, urlhacking

Created a URL that works fine, but I'm looking to add a count at the end of the Record name.

For example:

(Account Name) "Scorecard" {Count Field on Opp} + 1

Here is the URL:

/a0L/e?&retURL={!Opportunity.Id}&

CF00N3600000TJTHW_lkid={!Account.Id} &
CF00N3600000TJTHW={!Account.Name} &
& 
Name={!Account.Name} Scorecard {!Opportunity.Customer_Scorecard_Count__c} + 1

The Customer Scorecard Count field is a RUS.

Comment: well, you can make a formula, which will evaluate to Customer_Scorecard_Count__c + 1, and then use it in URL hack

Comment: That'll work, just wanted to see if there was a way to just add +1 to that number in the URL hack, which is looking like there isn't one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use formulas in your URL hacks, just like you can almost anywhere else. The following should work:

```
CF00N3600000TJTHW_lkid={!Account.Id}&
CF00N3600000TJTHW={!Account.Name}&
Name={!Account.Name} Scorecard {!Opportunity.Customer_Scorecard_Count__c+1}
```

(Line breaks added for legibility).